# Chrome Forcing HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Chrome is forcing https (as well as adding https to every internal link) to everything on my site, even though I have https support disabled/don't want to use it.

This occurred after I went to my site's cpanel (which requires you go through https). I changed no settings, and after that Chrome forces it. Only occurring on Chrome (firefox is working fine), and only on one computer.

Of course, I tried restarting, clearing cache/cookies as well as going to chrome://net-internals and deleting the domain from HSTS. Nothing works.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to all odds it had something to do with my website itself. In my case I'm running WordPress & WooCommerce on my site and it seems like by deactivating WooCommerce my issue was solved. Still not sure how to properly fix this since as soon as I activate WooCommerce again the same issue re-appears. However, at least I know now where the issue is coming from and can dig around further.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue with WooCommerce 2.3. Earlier versions don't have the same issue. My workaround was to load my site using Internet Explorer **{the horror}**.